# print a matrix through a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

```
int** mat = new int*[5];

// define the elements to be inserted to the matrix     
int* i1 = new int;
*i1 = 1;

int* i2 = new int;
*i2 = 2;

int* i3 = new int;
*i3 = 3;

int* i4 = new int;
*i4 = 4;

int* i5 = new int;
*i5 = 5;

// insert the elements to the matrix
mat[0] = i1;
mat[1] = i2;
mat[2] = i3;
mat[3] = i4;
mat[4] = i5;
```

now I define the pointer. I want to print the matrix through this pointer. so I define it:

```
int* ptr = *mat;
```

and here I print it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    ptr++;
}
```

but I got:

```
1
2543679
9826
257678
7853
```

please remember that I want to print it through a pointer (and do it ++) so relate only to the definition of the `ptr` and the `for loop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int* ptr = *mat;
```

is equivalent here to

```
int *ptr = i1;
```

so you let `ptr` point to the same place as `i1`. Then incrementing `ptr` makes it point one `int` behind where `i1` points. You have not allocated (and filled) memory there, so dereferencing the incremented pointer invokes undefined behaviour (and incrementing it further invokes undefined behaviour even without dereferencing).

To move through the array, you would need

```
int **ptr = mat;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << **ptr << endl;
    ptr++;
}
```

(but using subscripts

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << *mat[i] << endl;
}
```

would be more readable)

Comment: Bah, beat me to it :P Also, you may want to add a line, which clarifies that he probably wants to do new int[no_of_columns] for each row?